# Readline to Array or List output

Tags: python

I am new to Python and was recently given a problem to solve.

Briefly, I have a .csv file consisting of some data. I am supposed to read the .csv file and print out the first 5 column header names, followed by 5 rows of the data in the following format shown in the picture.
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osmqd.jpg)

Currently, I have written the code up to:

```py
readfiles = file.readlines()
for i in readfiles:
    data = i.strip()
    print(data)
```

and have managed to churn out all the data. However, I am not too sure how I can get the 5 rows of data which is required by the problem. I am thinking if the .csv file should be converted into an array/list? Hoping someone can help me on this. Thank you.

I can't use pandas or csv for this by the way. =/

Comment: So to clarify, you want to convert the first 5 rows to a list?

Comment: Hello, yes I think so! I'm presuming a list will be able to get me the output similar to the picture shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('\#pathtocsv.csv')
df.head()
```

if you want it in list

```
needed_list = df.head().tolist()
```

Comment: Please do not use `list` as an identifier(variable name)

Comment: Kavi just be aware excpro cannot use pandas

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to read a csv file, you can use `pandas` library to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/your/file")
print(df.columns[0:5]) # print first 5 column names
print(df.head(5)) # Print first 5 rows
```

Or if you want it to do without pandas then,

```
rows = []
with open("path/to/file.csv", "r") as fl:
    rows = [x.split(",") for x in fl.read().split("\n")]
print(rows[0][0:5]) # print first 5 column names
print(rows[0:5]) # print first 5 rows
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use pandas, so I have used your 2nd suggestion for the answer. I am working to get them aligned in a way that they fit the results now.